# Paragraph overlay in a table creating unwanted gaps around the edges

Tags: html, css

For my main page, I have four images nested in a table that are going to serve as links to other pages. On hover, I have a slightly transparent background with text overlaying the picture (a paragraph element). Everything works as wanted, however there is ~1px gap between the overlay and the edges of the table cell. I have messed around with margins and can get it to reach the top and left, but the bottom and right still have trouble. I am extremely new with html and css, any feedback is greatly appreciated!

and here's the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="hometable">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="homeimg" id="longboardingnav">
                    <p class="hidden">Longboarding</p>
                </td>
                <td class="homeimg" id="workinprogress1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="homeimg" id="workinprogress2"></td>
                <td class="homeimg" id="workinprogress3"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

#hometable {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.homeimg {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    height: 175px;
    width: 250px;
}

#longboardingnav {
    background-image: url(images/photo4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.homeimg .hidden {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(125,125,125,0.82);
    height: 77px;
    width: 152px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.homeimg:hover .hidden {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the padding on your cells

```
#hometable td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjhcD/6/)

Comment: Sorry, let me specify more. The unwanted gap is not in between table cells but in between the overlay on hover and the edge of the individual table cell.

Comment: @NegativeX3R0, See new answer.

Comment: Still no luck. Picture fits in table flush, just the overlay is having problems. Even after changing padding, overlay still has gap around edges.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to use 100% your code add a good link to the image -- with just added the css I have in my answer. The gap goes away.  Do you want the `border-collapse: collapse` back?

Comment: And that solved the problem! The first time I had altered padding under #hometable instead of the actual cell. Thanks so much for your help!